# TCP: when in TIME_WAIT state, will TCP starts a new 2MSL time if it receives a retransmitted FIN with 2MSL

Tags: networking, tcp

we know that when a TCP program is in TIME_WAIT state, it waits for a FIN for 2MSL.

if it receives a retransmitted FIN with 2MSL and retransmits an ACK, will it starts another
2MSL timeout or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the nuance of your question correctly, yes, the client will always wait the 2MSL. this doc may help: http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=2941